# Jquery Form not submitting on samsung devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, forms, samsung-mobile

I'm having a very strange error with my nodejs webapp and I was hoping you could help.  The app is for a game we are playing at our school.  It requires the user to signup on the homepage by filling in a form. The form is submitted to the backend (node js) using the jquery.forms plugin.  This seems to work perfectly fine on every device we have tested it on, but some of our users have said that they couldn't register.  The only common thing in each case is that the device was made by Samsung (note 5, galaxy s6, and a samsung laptop).  In all of these cases, there are no errors on the server (or even evidence of the request).

Has anyone ever encountered an issue like this?

Here is the code for the form and its submission:
http://pastebin.com/xapiSEih

And here is the backend code that processes the form (using multer for image uploads):
http://pastebin.com/1gxWHmMx

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It could be a certificate problem.  Verify that the certificate chains for your web sites and javascript sources are trusted by default in the OS of the devices that are reporting the issue.  Also, make sure your web server is configured to serve any intermediate certificates -- not just the leaf.

Comment: Have you tried different a different browser? Maybe javascript is disabled?